# Claiming a route using only locomotives in Ticket to Ride

Tags: ticket-to-ride

Are you able to claim the route between Little Rock and New Orleans using only locomotive cards.

Comment: There is no days of wonder expansion for ticket to ride, it is just a label that is on all of the boxes no matter what expansion it is. If you look at the web page you will see it on all of the boxes. https://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/

Comment: Days of Wonder is the publisher / distributor.

Comment: Thanks for posting this as a new question! I was about to make the following comment on the other post, but didn't get to it before it was cleaned up: I think this is a duplicate because the other question asks if there is a limit, and the answer says "No, there is no limit." If you feel that "No, there is no limit." is not clear enough to answer your question, please edit and explain more details about your uncertainty. Welcome!

Comment: @Judy Isenberg, Is Little Rock to New Orleans and example, or do you think there might be something special about that route specifically?

Comment: @GendoIkari, I do intend to add something like "you could even use only locomotives" to answer once possible.